# how to get records from db having one common column values with another list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

i have a list

`int ListA={23,25,41,69,20,22,30);`

and my db table contain column jobid(int) having values like
{20,61,55,14,21,12,0,11)etc

also it has a column for companyId(int)

Basic structure like

jobid  companyId

12        451

22        122

30        365  ...

I want to get those company ids from table whose job id exist in listA

i tried

`db.mqJobMasters.Where(e=>e.jobId==newlist2).Select(x=>x.jobCompanyId).ToList();`

but it gives error == connot applied to int to list

Comment: Please show us your attempt

Comment: `db.mqJobMasters.Where(e => listA.Contains(e.jobId)).Select(x => x.jobCompanyId).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
var result = db.mqJobMasters.Where(e=> listA.Contains(e.JobId)).Select(x=>x.jobCompanyId).ToList();
```